# How to implement multiple user profiles in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

In my project (a simple job board), I'd like to create some types of user such as `Admin, Employer, Seeker`. I already known implement Role management for this, but I want to implement different profile for each type. For example, `Employer (CompanyName, CompanyLogo,...)`, `Seeker (Name, Experience,...)`

In my current solution, I created `EmployerProfile`, `SeekerProfile` with the foreign key is UserId which was in relationship with `AspNetUsers` table.

I don't know how is my solution, any suggestion for this situation?

Thank you

Comment: EmployerProfile and SeekerProfile are out of bounds of Authorization implementation. Are you going to authorize by, for example, Employer Company Name? If not, once the user is authenticated and authorized by Role (ie Employer), you can get the EmployerProfile in DB using the FK UserId.